# extracting the block of data separated by symbols

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file that contain the data as follows

```
10.00      4.85   2.80  
16.00      6.25   3.61  
22.00      6.40   3.70  
25.00      6.80   3.79
>
100.00      4.85   2.80  
160.00      6.25   3.61  
220.00      6.40   3.70  
250.00      6.80   3.79
>
100.00      4.85   2.88
160.00      6.25   3.68  
220.00      6.40   3.78  
250.00      6.80   3.78
>
```

i want to read/print the portion of the data separated by > symbols in for loop

I tried the code

```
while read block
do
    ccc=sed 's/.*[>] * //' $block
    echo $ccc
done < filex
```

can anybody suggest a solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, please do mention your expected output in your question, thank you.

Comment: no output ,it gives error

Comment: every time in the loop i want to extract the lines that are in between > symbol

Comment: _print the portion_  ... Which portion? There are 3 portions in your example. Which one do you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting the input separator to ">" like this:

```
b=0; while read -d ">" blk ; do echo "block: $b"; echo $blk; ((b=b+1)); done < YOURFILE
```

**Sample Output**

```
block: 0
10.00      4.85   2.80  
16.00      6.25   3.61  
22.00      6.40   3.70  
25.00      6.80   3.79
block: 1
100.00      4.85   2.80  
160.00      6.25   3.61  
220.00      6.40   3.70  
250.00      6.80   3.79
block: 2
100.00      4.85   2.88
160.00      6.25   3.68  
220.00      6.40   3.78  
250.00      6.80   3.78
```

---

You can write it like this if you prefer:

```
b=0
while read -d ">" blk ; do
   echo "block: $b"
   echo $blk
   ((b=b+1))
done < YOURFILE
```

Comment: it doesnot give output

Comment: ok...how the files will be printed one by one instead of saving many files...as i have many files to do i just need to defined the block with the variable and later i want to use the same for other experiment

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand exactly what you are trying to do. I see multiple portions of data separated by `>`, so I don't know what you meant by "the portion of the data separated by > symbols".

But let's go through your script and see why it isn't working. Hope you get some inspiration from that.

```
while read block
do
    ...
done < filex
```

will loop over your file. The first iteration, `block` will contain

```
10.00      4.85   2.80
```

The second iteration, block will contain

```
16.00      6.25   3.61
```

et cetera.

Then, you write:

```
    ccc=sed 's/.*[>] * //' $block
```

In `bash`, this means execute the program `s/.*[>] * //` with the `ccc` set to `sed` and the contents of `block` as arguments (three arguments, `10.00`, `4.85` and `2.80` the first iteration. That is not what you want. You will get the error message `bash: s/.*[>] * //: No such file or directory` because `bash` cannot find that file.

To get the output of a command into a variable, use

```
ccc=$(sed .....)
```

`sed` either takes STDIN as input or, if specified, the files on the command line. So,

```
sed 's/.*[>] * //' $block
```

will make `sed` look (first iteration of the loop again) for the files `10.00`, `4.85` and `2.80`. `sed` will not use the line in `$block` as input. If you want `sed` to use `$block` as input, you should provide it as STDIN:

```
echo "$block" | sed '....`
```

or

```
ccc=$(echo "$block" | sed '...')
```

And finally some comments on the pattern.

`sed` will, for every line in the input, `'s/.*[>] * //'`. For every line of the input, not for some arbitrary block of lines. The pattern means:

```
/.*[>] * /
  | | | | 
  | | | \- and a single space
  | | \--- zero or more spaces
  | \----- the character > The [ and ] are normally used to give a list of
  |        possible characters.
  \------- zero or more characters
```

So, any line containing zero or more characters, followed by a `>`, zero or more spaces followed by a space, will have that part of the line deleted. Even when I do not understand what you want, that probably is not it.

Comment: every portion means lines between > symbols

Comment: so, basically `grep -v '>' filex | while read block; do echo $block; done` ?

Comment: can we write while loop forst then grep expression, please modify

Answer (score 0):

Just use grep:

```
grep -v '^>$'
```